# How can I install a Windows 8 application for another user and pin it on their Start screen?

Tags: windows-8, group-policy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a Network Administrator rearrange tiles on a user’s Start Menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/496537/can-a-network-administrator-rearrange-tiles-on-a-users-start-menu)

I am trying to create a locked down Windows 8 account using Group Policies with no tiles on the start screen except for one for the purposes of a Kiosk PC.

How can I (as an administrator account) install a custom application (side-loading) for another user and pin it to their start menu?

This application is still in development so will need to be updated frequently on the locked account for testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft provides a Technet Article about it:

[**How to Customize the Start Screen**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj134269.aspx#BKMK_AppFolder).

The layout is stored in a file called

```
appsFolderLayout.bin/appsFolder.itemdata-ms.
```

You have to copy this file to each account that needs the layout.